# Hidden form submits on enter key pressed

Tags: model-view-controller

I've two form in the page. One is hidden by default. The hidden form submits when I press enter from keyboard.

How to avoid that ?

I've two form. One is HttpGet and another one is HttpPost. But when press enter key from keyboard, It always call HttpPost instead of HttpGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities to resolve this.

1. Remove the form which is in Http.Get.
2. If it is required, then have different action names for HttpGet and HttpPost.